# How to split lines in a file and put data into a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, split

I am trying read a txt file and put the data into a dictionary. My file looks something like this:

```
Alex:3
John:6
Sam:8
```

Basically, a word and integer separated by a colon. I want to open and read the file, split each line where the colon is, and put the data into a dictionary like this:

{'Alex':3, 'John':6, 'Sam':8}

So far my code looks like this:

```
d = {}
f = open('scores.txt', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    name = line.split(":")
```

How do I assign the name as the key and the integer as the value and put it into the dictionary?

Comment: `d = dict(line.strip().split(':') for line in open('scores.txt'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
d = {}
f = open('scores.txt', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    name,score = line.split(":")
    d[name] = int(score)
```

[str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) returns a list of all the tokens in the string.  You can grab both of these values using the syntax I showed.

You can then index it in the dictionary via the name variable, as you can see.

Edit: As @MauroBaraldi in the comments points out, you don't need the `line.strip()` anymore as `int()` will do that work for you.

Comment: Answers containing only code and no explanation are usually not helpful.

Comment: @ErlVolton I usually post code first then edit a more detailed description in immediately after.  Sorry.

Comment: score is not int, but str

Comment: You could remove `line = line.strip()` line too, `int` does the work.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with

```
name = line.split(":")
```

`split()` will return a list.  You can unpack the list like this:

```
name, othervalue = line.split(":")
```

And then do:

```
mydict[name] = othervalue
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are another approach to solve the problem.

```
with open('scores.txt') as fp:
    result = {}
    for line in fp.readlines():
        key, value = line.split(':')
        result[key] = int(value)
```

A good practice is open files using `with`. It closes automatically when get out of context.

Answer (score -1):

```
d = {}
f = open('scores.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    name,age= line.strip(":")
    d[name]=age
```

In the above code, `line.strip()` will remove the new line character, `line.split(":")` will split the string on ":", so you will get two value name and age that will be stored.   `d[name]=age` name is key and age will be the value stored

Comment: Answers containing only code and no explanation are usually not helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use following code to get desired output. You can separate the words by using **split** . **rstrip** is used to remove the newline.

```
 f = open('file name')

 dic = {}

 for l in f:

     k,v = l.split(':')
     v=v.rstrip('\n')

     if k in dic:

         dict.update({k:v })

     else:

         dic[k] = [v]
  print dic
```

output:

```
   {'John': ['6'], 'Alex': ['3'], 'Sam': ['8']}
```